# Standard naming of DAO and Hibernate classes

Tags: java, hibernate, coding-style

This is just a question on naming classes.
I want to know the "standard" (or most accepted) approach to naming DAOs and their Hibernate implementations.

Should it be?

- HibenateDOMAINDAO
- DOMAINDAOHibernate
- HibernateDAODOMAIN

etc

Personally, I naturally go for HibernateDOMAINDao, but I have gotten into a little discussion about this a colleague who prefers DOMAINDAOHibernate.

Comment: HibernateDomainDAO, certainly not the third one.

Answer (score 4):

I usually prefer namespaces.

Something like

```
com.something.proyect.dao.Dao //Generic Dao Interface
com.something.proyect.dao.DomainDao // DomainDao Interface
com.something.proyect.dao.hibernate.HibernateBaseDao // Base Hibernate Impl
com.something.proyect.dao.hibernate.DomainDaoImpl // Hibernate Domain Dao Impl
com.something.proyect.dao.jdbc.JdbcBaseDao // JDBC Base impl
com.something.proyect.dao.jdbc.DomainDaoImpl // JDBC Domain DAo Impl
com.something.proyect.dao.anotherorm.AnotherOrmBaseDaoImpl
```

That way I just know that anything under hibernate is, well, hibernate and I don't have to append Hibernate to my Classes.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Dao abbreviation is Data Access Object, It's design pattern we use[Dao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object),So it's not only related to hibernate we can use it in any programming language(As I know),

```
com.orm.dao.GenericDao // Generic Interface which uses every interface in the Dao layer,This has common methods like create,delete,update etc

com.orm.dao.DomainDao // Extended from Generic dao, additionally contains domain specific moethods

com.orm.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl // Implementation of GenericDao interface, normally this class should be abstract  

com.orm.dao.impl.DomainDaoImpl // Implementation of DomainDao interface and extended from GenericDaoImpl class
```

Hope this will clear for you,
Cheers